# Calling Python functions from other python files?

Tags: python

Sorry if this is 'old hat', but I'd like to find the "proper" way to do this:

I have 2 python files, Foo.py and Bar.py such that

Foo.py calls FuncB() that's in Bar.py and
Bar.py calls FuncF() that's in Foo.py.

If each file does an import of the other, won't this cause some kind of problem, or is the correct way of doing this using 'from Bar import FuncB'?

Comment: Have you tried various combinations to see what works and what doesn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: `from Bar import FuncB` and vice verse should do the trick.`

Comment: Bear in mind that if you need to do this, your structure may be wrong.

Comment: You can not do this without checking for a main script.

Answer (score 0):

The following imports work fine, even though `Foo` and `Bar` import each other. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python) gets into more detail about why.

### Foo.py

```
import Bar

def printFoo():
   print "Foo says hi"

def main():
    Bar.printBar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Bar.py

```
import Foo

def printBar():
   print "Bar says hi"

def main():
    Foo.printFoo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks...I was concerned that with each importing the other that there would be problems.